# Change swedish appendix title 'bilaga' to 'appendix'

Tags: appendices

I'm writing a document in Swedish, and appendices are then called 'bilaga' which is a translation of 'appendix' not widely used in my field. Hence, I'd like the title in appendix A to read *'Appendix A'* and not *'Bilaga A'*. I've tried using `\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}` but it changes nothing. The toc is fine as it is - doesn't use the word *Appendix* or *Bilaga* at all, just A, B and so on.

EDIT: Don't know what a MWE is, but here are pieces of my latex code that I think may be relevant:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
%...{lots of other stuff related to figures and page layout}
\usepackage{appendix}

\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter{oneone}

bla1 bla1

\chapter{twotwo}

bla

\appendix
\chapter{titel first appendix}

appendix text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add an MWE of what you tried so far?

Comment: `\addto\captionsswedish{\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}}`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: I don't think these questions are identical.

Comment: Christian Hupfers solution works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: answered you have!  Well done!

Comment: @Jan but Christian is giving the exact same answer being accepted by Carina...

Comment: @Carina: mind you editing your question title to contain swedish?  For example: "Changing appendix title in swedish documents"?  Could be easier to find in the search.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: Huh??? I used the traditional way. `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}}` should work too.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: nope.  This question is at least not duplicate to the given link of yours.  Carina wanted to restore the name of the appendix which was defined in swedish, while the question in your link wants to add the word "Appendix" into the table of contents.  The solution to this question is by far not `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{foo}`, but the trick is to also add `\addto\captionsswedish{}`.  That is completely not mentioned in your link.

Comment: @Jan: I gave in to my TeX anger ;-)

Comment: @Carina Change `spanish` to `swedish` in the answer by Gonzalo to the linked question.

Comment: The nice outcome of this post: I learned that `bilaga` is `Appendix` in Swedish ;-) It resembles German `Beilage` strikingly